# Monitor hung instances of a powershell script

Tags: scripting, powershell, process, kill

I´m writing a Powershell script to do a bunch of things and when finished it will be run as a scheduled task. For that reason I want to be able to check whether an older instance is still alive when I start running the script and kill the older one if it exists.

I was thinking I would use something like this:

```
$process = Get_Process | $name
$process.kill
```

But how to get the $name variable in a simple way?

Does anyone have a better suggestion?
Best regards,
Gísli

Comment: Are you sure that there isn't a way to stop the script from hanging? I would focus on creating a reliable script rather than resort to killing processes.

Comment: @Ryant - Of course I'm trying to do this properly but I need this as a safety net for my application because it will be running on servers I don't have access to. This is just to make sure that I don't stack up a whole lot of processes and drain the servers resources.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this in windows scheduled task configuration. The settings depends on the OS you are using though.

EDIT: that is you can configure the task to be killed after a certain period of time (i.e. when your next one starts).

Comment: Thanks. This could be an option, I have to check with my mentor. I'm rewriting a script he had written in perl and he had a function in there to kill the processes. That might be because it had to run on multiple platforms.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need to get the name? `Get-Process` returns high fidelity  `Process` objects and you can operate on it directly.

To get a process of a particular name use `$n = Get-Process notepad`, say, and then do `$n.kill()` to kill it. If you do need to check the name again, do `$n.Name`. To see what properties and methods you can use, try `$n | get-member`

And make sure you read the manual: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347630.aspx

Comment: This doesn't address @Gisli's problem. There could be multiple powershell processes running, how will the script know which one(s) should be killed? One powershell.exe process will be for the script itself, one could be an active console session, another could be from a different task, etc.

Comment: @Rynant - Of course. I am addressing his specific question regarding get-process. Helping move towards the solution he can find out. Purpose of stackoverflow is not to give the entire thing so that the OP can just do it.